# Websockets won't work on docker with nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, websocket

I have a problem with a real-time chat application on Django. The websockets won't work on nginx server. Am I missing something?

The app only says: `/ws/socket-server/` not found

[image]

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream project {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://project;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    #path to proxy my WebSocket requests
    location /ws/socket-server/ {

        proxy_pass http://project;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

}
```

**asgi.py**

```
    """
ASGI config for project project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import scrumboard.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            scrumboard.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
from django.template.context_processors import media

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

DEBUG = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=0))

# 'DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS' should be a single string of hosts with a space between each.
# For example: 'DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(" ")
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:1337']
CORS_ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://localhost:1337']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'scrumboard',
    'rest_framework'
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer'
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.environ.get("SQL_ENGINE", "django.db.backends.sqlite3"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("SQL_DATABASE", BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("SQL_USER", "user"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD", "password"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("SQL_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("SQL_PORT", "5432"),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<<>>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<<>>'
```

**routing.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path
    from . import consumers
    
    websocket_urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'ws/socket-server/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
    ]
```

Comment: Which ASGI server are you using?  Daphne, Uvicorn?

Comment: I tried connecting to daphne by running daphne -p 8001 project.asgi:application. And i added an upstream to nginx config file, but can't seem to really connect to daphne. It says "Connection refused for upstream <daphne URL>"

Comment: Currently, the nginx server is used as a reverse proxy for static files, which works properly.

Comment: I asked because I didn't see daphne in your INSTALLED_APPS.  I'm not sure why you get a connection refused, but I think you *must* have daphne or another asgi server for the websockets to work.  Putting daphne back in and troubleshooting the connection refused is where I would start.

Answer (score -2):

No, websockets will not work on Docker with nginx. WebSockets require persistent connections, which are not supported by Nginx. To enable websockets on Docker, you must use a reverse proxy, such as HAProxy or Apache.

Comment: Websockets work fine with nginx if properly configured!

Comment: @KlausD, do you have any advice for my problem?